# standing wave in a capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism

From what I've read in the answer to another post

[Does a charging capacitor emit an electromagnetic wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20126/does-a-charging-capacitor-emit-an-electromagnetic-wave)

it is at least imaginable that a capacitor without dielectric can be charged / discharged very fast (THz scale) using a signal generator.  At this frequency, the field between the plate is not quasistatic, and the changing charge on the plates should generate an EM wave between the plates.

My questions is about the wavelength of the wave.  Another post suggested that the wavelength is equal to the plate separation.  Does this mean that only certain frequencies could be used to drive the charge between the two plates, similar to an atom only exciting with certain frequencies?  What would happen if one tried to use a different frequency such that c/f was not a multiple of the plate separation?  Would there be some internal impedance that prevents this charging unless the frequency was just right?

Comment: You should properly refer to these posts.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20126/does-a-charging-capacitor-emit-an-electromagnetic-wave